# Keras validation loss fluctuates

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, loss-function

I'm training an `LSTM` model created with `Keras`.
During epochs, I notice that the training loss decreases epoch after epoch, but validation loss fluctuates.
The fluctuation is small.

The number of features of my examples are 837.

Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=400, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Losses for the first 10 epochs:

```
loss: 0.3362 - val_loss: 0.3306
loss: 0.3320 - val_loss: 0.3302
loss: 0.3304 - val_loss: 0.3298
loss: 0.3286 - val_loss: 0.3308
loss: 0.3271 - val_loss: 0.3303
loss: 0.3260 - val_loss: 0.3315
loss: 0.3254 - val_loss: 0.3302
loss: 0.3246 - val_loss: 0.3309
loss: 0.3246 - val_loss: 0.3316
loss: 0.3241 - val_loss: 0.3312
```

Here's the plot:

[image: Training and validation loss]

Is this a bad behavior?

In general, when it happens?

Comment: This could be due to your validation data being too different from your training data. As such, even though it is fitting to the training data, it doesn't seem to generalise to your validation data.

Comment: @VincentYong I’m using 20% of training set as validation data (`validation_split=0.2`). Could the model have too much hidden units?